# Values assigned to Array are stored as numbers, not as text

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm populating an array from several columns. In one column there are sometimes numbers, letters or a combination of it.
The numbers in the source are formatted as text. Meaning I have leading zero's.
When the array is populated, it converts the text to numbers. This means I lose my leading zero's if applicable. But I need this.

What did I tried to so far:

1. formatting the sheet where the array will post it to (will not work as the values in the array are already as numbers and lost the leading zero's);
2. Changed `Dim myArray() as Variant` to `Dim myArray() as String`;
3. Changed `Dim i, j, k as Long` to `Dim i, j, k as String`;
4. use `Cstr` to store the data in the array as a string;

This is my code what I have now:

```
numberOfRecords = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1

Dim myArray() As String
Dim i, j, k As Long
k = 0
ReDim myArray(numberOfRecords, 2 To 6) As String

For i = 2 To numberOfRecords
    If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, 
        Sheets("SE16N").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
            For j = 2 To 6
                myArray(k, j) = CStr(Cells(i, j).Text)
                Debug.Print myArray(k, j) 'Just to check how the array is storing data
            Next j
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
```

I hope someone can help me.

I can only post 2 links as I don't have a reputation of 10 yet at Stack Overflow. Therefore only to sure for sure I have leading zero's and with the local windows view.

[With leading zero's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MWlJ.jpg)
[Local Windows view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYGk5.jpg)

Comment: Are you aware that `Dim i, j, k as String` means that i and j are variants and k is a string? Also, to preserve your leading zeros, use the `.Text` property instead of the `.Value` property.

Comment: Using `Cells(i, j).Text` will return what is actually displayed rather than the value which will ignore the formatting.

Comment: `Dim i, j, k As String` also seems a bit weird when you are using `i,j,k` as numerical indices. You probably want `Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long`

Comment: Hi braX,

Thanks for looking into this. No, I was not aware of the fact that i and j are variants and k a string. I'm still relatively new to arrays and trying to get a hold on it.
I thought if you declare variables separated by a comma and in this case as String, all these variables will be a string. Or is it because the way I use these variables?

I changed the line which populates the array to Cstr(Cells(i, j).Text), but I still lose my leading zero's.

Comment: The way VBA handles `Dim` statements and types is arguably a design flaw. You need to be explicit for each variable. VBA can be quirky and there are several pitfalls that you need to be aware of if you are coming from another programming language (such as the fact that Boolean operators don't use short-circuit evaluation).

Comment: are you really, really sure that the data in the cells has leading zeros? the cell format may be set to display leading zeros, when in fact, the data actually has no leading zeros.

Comment: Hi jsotola,
Yes, I'm pretty sure. The settings of the respective cells are set to text, it shows a green triangle in the corner and doesn't use " ' " in front of the number, yet it shows 1 zero up to several zero's in front of the number. I included an image from the original data with 3 leading zero's and the result after the macro where the leading zero's are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to go around this issue: I changed the format of the respective column to text manually which is a one time effort.
Initially in my code I had range.clear, but now I use range.clearcontent. Clearcontent doesn't remove the formatting of the column.
Now it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get values from cells is:

```
Dim vData As Variant
vData = Range("A2:A10").Value
```

You should get strings as strings and numbers as numbers.

Comment: Hi jkpieterse,

That's the whole point. Numbers need to be strings as well. If I use numbers I will lose my leading zero's.

Comment: Numbers which are stored in cells formatted as text are text have you tried my example and looked at what ends up in vData in the View, Locals window?

Comment: If I make a short function based on your code I get a type mismatch error (type 13):

    Sub test()
    Dim vData As Variant
    vData = Worksheets("Source").Range("E1:E10").Value 'I took a range in column E as there are the numbers with the leading zero's
    Debug.Print vData
    End Sub

Comment: You cannot debug.print an entire array in one go. CLick View, Locals Window to see the contant of vData.

Comment: Hi jkpieterse,
I included a screenshot from the local window view. there it shows the leading zero's. However, the data is not stored in an array. Can that be the point?

Comment: As you see the leading zeroes are there, so it MUST be text.